# Cannot resolve scoped service.Identity.UserManager[User] from root provider

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to integrate AspNetCore.Identity and I am getting an exception that it cannot resolve scoped service.Identity.UserManager[MyUser] from root provider. I have seen many similar questions, but in all of them there was some sort of resolving going on, e.g. `app.ApplicationServices.GetService(..)`, which was the cause of the problem because they were resolving from the root container and not a scoped one. So my guess is that some of the code is resolving behind the scenes?

I also tried to make UserManager a singleton by calling `services.AddSingleton<UserManager<User>>();` but then it was complaining about IUserStore not being a singleton... So I could see myself "fixing" all those scopes for the AspNetCore.Identity service registrations but that is probably a workaround for the real problem.

I can post the DbContext as well if that is of any help.

What can I do to fix the issue?

Program.cs

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var webHostBuilder = CreateHostBuilder(args);
    var host = webHostBuilder.Build();
    host.Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    RegisterEmailStuff(services);
    
    RegisterIdentityStuff(services);
    
    services.AddMvc(
        options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }
    );
    
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
}

public static void RegisterIdentityStuff(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions<ServiceProviderOptions>().Configure(options => options.ValidateScopes = false);

    IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

    services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddScoped<MyContext>();

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        //options.Password...
        //options.Lockout...
        //options.User....
        //options.SignIn....
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Login");

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
        });

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();            
}

public void RegisterEmailStuff(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<SmtpSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SmtpSettings"));
    services.AddSingleton<IMailer, Mailer>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto}); 

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
    app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
}
```

The full exception is

```
An error occurred while starting the application.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[User]' from root provider.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[User]' from root provider.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope, IServiceScope rootScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.IServiceProviderEngineCallback.OnResolve(Type serviceType, IServiceScope scope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, object[] parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
Webserver.Program.Main(string[] args) in Program.cs
host.Run();
```

Comment: The exception stack-trace suggests that `JwtMiddleware` might be the problem here. Do you inject `UserManager` into `JwtMiddleware`'s constructor?

Comment: You are on the spot! That there is nothing related to JwtMiddleware in the exception put me off. I thought it's some magic elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same error for the same reason apparently - I am injecting UserManager in JwtMiddleware's constructor.. How did you work around this? I need access to User data in that class